# Freeware x86 decompilers for Windows with debug?

Tags: gratis, debugging, reverse-engineering

I'm searching for a software that is capable of decompiling x86 code in C-like code and run a debug session within it with the possibility to see the content of the variables.

That above was a quick summary, let me explain better here. I'm trying to recreate a master server for an old game that will have its master server taken down (and now its not working good because it uses deprecated TLS technologies, you have to enable some option in windows). Because of this, I sniffed all the traffic that I was able to make (running trough mitmproxy) and already having a full playable server. One functionality is still not working, because the master server is not sending back data (is a "news" section of the in-game browser).

The only thing I would like to know reverse engineering the executable of the game is the format how that response should be sent by the master server to have it shown in the game. I know for sure it should be not encrypted (nothing between the communication is, is in ASCII plaintext, encrypted in a lower level via SSL). Once I will be able to know how the format of the response was, the data should not be a problem. I've tried bruteforcing like other response from the server, but checking a decompiler, it seems it parses in a different way.

I've tried some disassemblers, but following assembly code is not the easiest thing to do. Also following a C pseudocode without debugging is not the easiest, I'm not C expert (I'm more a high-level programmer), altough I know the theory behind both x86 assembly and C. I've tried

- IDA freeware: it starts debugging perfectly, but cannot understand the memory structure inside it, so I could not understand why the conditions that make the game failing to read the response are behaving like that.
- Binary Ninja Debugger demo: good C like code, but can not start the debugger at all.
- Cutter debug: good C code, but the breakpoints are not stopping by.

I don't need to modify the code, or recompile it. I hope my question is clear :)

Thank you.

Comment: Hey there, could you describe the goal a bit more? Going by what you write, I would assume that a packet sniffer like WireShark (perhaps with your own dissector) could be a good fit, given it's not encrypted. Another way to tackle this sort of thing - depending on the used network functions - would be an [LSP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/categorizing-layered-service-providers-and-applications). Also even with decompilers chances are you need to know a bare minimum of assembly, because their output can be quite suboptimal.

Comment: Yes, I'll explain. I've used WireShark and Mitmproxy with stellar result. The server code is working. But, there is a button in the GUI of the game to retrieve the latest news from the develepor, but I receive 0 reply from the script. Trying to emulate responses, the game cannot parse them and give me error. If I put the actual response from the real server, I get 0 news. I would really like to have this feature restored too (and, apart from hidden ones, with that I would have 100% working GUI). The game is Trackmania Nations ESWC, (not the newest "Forever").

Comment: I've tried the newest IDA pro free 8.3, that decompiled with C++ pseudo code (the thing I asked in this question)... but still I couldn't understand which data the server should return to have the data parsed and shown on the client GUI. The rest of the server was pretty easy (thanks to real data sniffed), but it was always an ASCII string.

Comment: So the goal is to get around the fact that it doesn't work on modern Windows versions or to be able to replicate the server-side only?

Comment: The goal is to create a master server, so when the official one will close it will still be possible to play online. I will publish the code after some time when the master server will be shut down. When the client connects, it will ask for news to the master server. Actually, the official one responds with 0 news. If I try to return something, the client tell me the format of the response is not valid. I would like to restore this news functionality (after one guy removed the starforce protection, giving the possibility to play it on modern operating systems)

Comment: A precisation: the game already has the Starforce protection removed, it is not encrypted anymore.

Comment: Were you able to locate the code that processes the news response or are you still hunting for that, though?

Comment: This should be easy, because I can step by step until the breakpoint on the corresponding server call is triggered. But then, in the client, I can not find the string in the memory map (I can find it on the system dll, but when the control goes back to the application, I can not see anywhere the string). I try to follow step by step, and after some transformations I receive the error on the client, so that should be the portion of code that does the validation.

Comment: The same code is present also in the dedicated server program (that calls the master server I'm creating), but I think that code is disabled via a costant because I never go trough it during the handshaking dedicated server <-> master server.